# Group Timeseries into uneven frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
    timestamp             price
0   2020-01-01 00:00:03     5
1   2020-01-01 00:03:03     10
2   2020-01-01 00:08:03     10
3   2020-01-01 00:09:03     10
4   2020-01-01 00:10:03     5
5   2020-01-01 00:13:03     10
6   2020-01-01 00:18:03     10
7   2020-01-01 00:19:03     10
```

Code for creating it is

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01 00:00:03', 5], ['2020-01-01 00:03:03', 10], ['2020-01-01 00:08:03', 10], ['2020-01-01 00:09:03', 10], ['2020-01-01 00:10:03', 5], ['2020-01-01 00:13:03', 10], ['2020-01-01 00:18:03', 10], ['2020-01-01 00:19:03', 10]], columns= ['timestamp', 'price'])
```

I can use a grouper like this to convert it into even groups of 10 minutes.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq="10Min", label='left')).sum()
```

But but how can achieve uneven groups of 9 minute and 1 minutes and so on giving result like this:

```
timestamp                 price
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00     25
1   2020-01-01 00:09:00     10
2   2020-01-01 00:10:00     25
3   2020-01-01 00:19:00     10
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any documentation about grouping over alternating frequencies, so the best solution I could come up with is to break your original dataframe into 1 minute sections, then iterate through it, alternating adding up 9 minutes of data, and 1 minute of data.

I acknowledge that it's a bit hacky, and that iterating through dataframes isn't ideal.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01 00:00:03', 5], ['2020-01-01 00:03:03', 10], 
    ['2020-01-01 00:08:03', 10], ['2020-01-01 00:09:03', 10], ['2020-01-01 00:10:03', 5], 
    ['2020-01-01 00:13:03', 10], ['2020-01-01 00:18:03', 10], ['2020-01-01 00:19:03', 10]], 
    columns= ['timestamp', 'price'])

# to use pd.Grouper, you need to have your index set to a datetime format
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

# split the dataframe into segments of 1 minute
df_minutes = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1Min", label='left')).sum()

# Create your final df that will be filled
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["price"])
final_df.index.name = "timestamp"

# the counter i will group your df into multiples of 10 by its length
for i in range(int(len(df_minutes) / 10)):
    # sum together the first 9 minutes
    start = 10*i
    end = start + 9
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df_minutes[start:end].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="10Min", label='left')).sum()])
    # then the next 1 minute
    start = 10*i + 9
    end = start + 1
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df_minutes[start:end].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1Min", label='left')).sum()])
```

Output:

```
>>> final_df
                    price
timestamp                
2020-01-01 00:00:00    25
2020-01-01 00:09:00    10
2020-01-01 00:10:00    25
2020-01-01 00:19:00    10
```